# Convert all the columns from the first row into single column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this,

```
EmpID  EmpName  Age  DOB
123    user     43   30/06/85
122    user1    42   31/07/86
```

I need a out put in this format,

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
EmpID    123      122
EmpName  user     user1
Age      43       42
DOB      30/06/85 31/07/86
```

And note the number of columns in table A will keep on increasing, so if I use `unpivot` to achieve this, I cannot hard code the column names.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. Your answer depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post on pivots with dynamic columns. http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/default.aspx

btw, for my own bias, I'm assuming SQL server but it would be helpful in future to tag the specific DBMS you're using

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I could assist!